# Backbone js template is not loading through dynamic jsp

Tags: javascript, jsp, backbone.js, backbone-views

I'm using backbone js for my project where I render a view like this---

```
      var View1 = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: "#container",
        initialize: function (){
            this.render();
        },

        render: function(){
            var parent = this;

            $.get('http://localhost:8080/pages/task.jsp').done(function (data){
                parent.$el.html(data);
                var view = new ViewTask1()
            })
        }
    });
```

Inside task.jsp , I have a template that i wish to render separately. The file looks something like this,..

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary">A simple primary list group item</li>

</ul>


<div id="abc"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="task-card-template">
    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Then i insert some data into a collection, map the collection to a model and try to render this template as follows:

```
//Create Task View
var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function() {
        this.render();
    },

  template: _.template($('#task-card-template').html()),

  render: function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
    return this;
  }

});

var ViewTask1 = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : "#abc",
    initialize : function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render : function() {
         this.$el.html('');

         Tasks.each(function(model) {
            var task = new TaskView({
                model : model
            });

            this.$el.append(task.render().el);
        }.bind(this));

        return this;
    },
});
```

Yet i get the error saying, **TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Function.h.template** from underscore js. 
At first, i thought maybe the jsp is not loaded or View1 is not rendered before the calling the template views(ViewTask) , but as I have checked it is being called after the JSP is fully rendered.
My question is How do i load templates from inside the views?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track... it looks like you are defining your template function inside `TaskView` right at pageload, before your ajax has a chance to add the needed html to your page. Even though you don't create any *instances* of `TaskView` before the ajax completes, the view definition is still trying to use that html right away.

I think you have two possible solutions: (1) Define your template function inside the `initialize` or `render` method which won't exectute until you have an instance. Or (2) put the html somewhere right on your page (in a hidden div maybe) so that it can be fetched right away.

Solution (1) might look a bit like this:

```
var TaskView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    // no template method yet
    render: function() {
        // inside render method, define template method if not already defined
        if (!this.template) {
            this.template = _.template($('#task-card-template').html());
        }
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.attributes));
        return this;
    }
});
```